# weblogic , unix , logs

Tags: logging, weblogic, logserver

Hi I have weblogic server and soa server in AIX machine 
Are files like core2012.dmp , javacore2012.txt , Snap2012.trc safe to delete from weblogic domain ? I'm running out of space and these files are getting very big .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest moving them somewhere out of the way before deleting them so you can in fact put them back if it causes an issue, but I yes I am sure you can remove these safely (I have in the past on non-AIX machines: Solaris,Linux)

More importantly, I would suggest analysing these dump files to see why they are being created, and addressing that issue

A good resource for that can be found here ( I googled for 'weblogic core dump files'):

http://weblogicfordummies.blogspot.com.au/2010/03/analyzing-core-dump-file.html

or

http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4482

Answer (score 0):

Those looks like core dumps and traces for process with PID 2012. This means that you have a bug in a native library. You should be able to see the stack trace at the dump time.

You might need to upgrade some libraries used by JVM and/or upgrade JDK.